# Create and run custom T4 template with input parameters?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to create and run own template with some input parametres? 
*Something like MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework* in ASP .NET MVC 4.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You use partial classes to add parameters to the template. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) can get you started.

The idea is that having the following template named `MyTemplate.tt` :

```
<table>
    <# for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
       { #>
         <tr><td>Test name <#= i #> </td>
             <td>Test value <#= i * i #> </td> </tr>
    <# } #>
</table>
```

Then you can add a partial class in a separated file, for example `MyTemplateExtension.cs`, where you can set your own properties:

```
partial class MyTemplate
{
    private MyData m_data;
    public MyTemplate(MyData data) { this.m_data = data; }
}
```

And use those properties in the template:

```
<h2>Sales figures</h2>
<table>
<# foreach (MyDataItem item in m_data.Items) 
   // m_data is declared in MyTemplateExtension.cs
   { #>
      <tr><td> <#= item.Name #> </td>
          <td> <#= item.Value #> </td></tr>
<# } // end of foreach
#>
</table>
```

You now have a template with a constructor that receives parameters and can be used in the following way:

```
MyTemplate templateGenerator = new MyTemplate(data);
String report = templateGenerator.TransformText();
```

Comment: Thnx. But this example is about runtime template. I want something that like MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework. Pass parameters via GUI.

Comment: @user2457382 Sorry, I understood you were interested in a runtime template _like running a read/write action and view using EF_ :)